# My files from other git branch are added to my newly checked out branch

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have been working with git for quite some time and mostly I use GUI(IntelliJ Idea) for all my staging, commiting and pushing of the code to the remote repo.
But when I try to use command line commands this problem persists `My files from other git branch are added to my newly checked out branch`.
Can anyone helpme out on this!!
Thanks in Advance!

I tried to switch branches to work on other files which weren't supposed to be my current branch.But as soon as I checkout from current branch to new branch some files are being added to newly checked out branch.To solve this I usually delete the newly added files!!

Comment: Are the files tracked by git ?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the files (tracked or untracked) are **not** committed, if you are able to successfully checkout a different branch, untracked files or tracked files with changes will go along with you when you switch.... it's a feature, not a bug.

If you have modified tracked files and you ask git to checkout a different branch, git will *only* allow you to checkout *if* the modified untracked files are the same between HEAD and the place where you want to go (checkout ends up with the files as you had them in the working tree... which means they will show up as being modified after the checkout). If that is not the case (files are not the same between HEAD and where you want to go), checkout fails (unless you run with `-f` in which case you *will* lose the changes on those files).